# Uncaught ReferenceError: angular is not defined - AngularJS not working

Tags: javascript, angularjs, button, angularjs-directive

I'm attempting to learn angular and I am struggling with a simple button click.
I followed an example which has an identical code to the one below.

The result I am looking for is for the button click to cause an alert. However, there is no response to the button click. Does anybody have any ideas?

```
<html lang="en" ng-app="myApp" >
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>My AngularJS App</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/app.css"/>
</head>
<body>
    <div >
        <button my-directive>Click Me!</button>
    </div>

    <script>
        var app = angular.module('myApp',[]);

        app.directive('myDirective',function(){

            return function(scope, element,attrs) {
                element.bind('click',function() {alert('click')});
            };

        });
    </script>

    <h1>{{2+3}}</h1>

  <!-- In production use:
  <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.7/angular.min.js"></script>
  -->
  <script src="lib/angular/angular.js"></script>
  <script src="lib/angular/angular-route.js"></script>
  <script src="js/app.js"></script>
  <script src="js/services.js"></script>
  <script src="js/controllers.js"></script>
  <script src="js/filters.js"></script>
  <script src="js/directives.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Could it be caused by angular being loaded after your custom script?

Comment: If you are getting the error given in the title then there would not even be a button to click.

Answer (score 79, accepted):

You need to move your angular app code below the inclusion of the angular libraries. At the time your angular code runs, `angular` does not exist yet. This is an error (see your dev tools console).

In this line:

```
var app = angular.module(`
```

you are attempting to access a variable called `angular`. Consider what causes that variable to exist. That is found in the angular.js script which must then be included first.

```
  <h1>{{2+3}}</h1>

  <!-- In production use:
  <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.7/angular.min.js"></script>
  -->
  <script src="lib/angular/angular.js"></script>
  <script src="lib/angular/angular-route.js"></script>
  <script src="js/app.js"></script>
  <script src="js/services.js"></script>
  <script src="js/controllers.js"></script>
  <script src="js/filters.js"></script>
  <script src="js/directives.js"></script>

      <script>
        var app = angular.module('myApp',[]);

        app.directive('myDirective',function(){

            return function(scope, element,attrs) {
                element.bind('click',function() {alert('click')});
            };

        });
    </script>
```

For completeness, it is true that your directive is similar to the already existing directive `ng-click`, but I believe the point of this exercise is just to practice writing simple directives, so that makes sense.

Comment: @m59. Besides what you stay, he still has to add the ng-app directive to initialize angularjs. See my js-fiddle code below

Comment: @ŽeljkoSzep huh? He has the `ng-app` directive already. It's in the first line of his code.

Comment: @m59. What a blunder. I copied only the body part from his code into js-fiddle as it already includes the html tag, so I missed the line with the ng-app directive. Sorry. I deleted my answer.

Answer (score 5):

Use the `ng-click` directive:

```
<button my-directive ng-click="alertFn()">Click Me!</button>

// In <script>:
app.directive('myDirective' function() {
  return function(scope, element, attrs) {
    scope.alertFn = function() { alert('click'); };
  };
};
```

Note that you don't need `my-directive` in this example, you just need something to bind `alertFn` on the current scope.

**Update**:
You also want the angular libraries loaded before your `<script>` block.

Comment: And what @m59 said - you need the angular libraries first. :)

Answer (score 3):

Just to complement [m59's correct answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21440353/1429387), here is a working [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zeljko/UKU7p/):

```
<body ng-app='myApp'>
    <div>
        <button my-directive>Click Me!</button>
    </div>
     <h1>{{2+3}}</h1>

</body>
```

Comment: Seems the guys from jsfiddle deleted my code snippet,

Answer (score 0):

As you know `angular.module`( declared under angular.js file.So before accessing angular.module, you must have make it available by using  `<script src="lib/angular/angular.js"></script>`(In your case) after then you can call `angular.module`. It will work.

like

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>My AngularJS App</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/app.css"/>
<!-- In production use:
  <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.7/angular.min.js"></script>
  -->
  <script src="lib/angular/angular.js"></script>
  <script src="lib/angular/angular-route.js"></script>
  <script src="js/app.js"></script>
  <script src="js/services.js"></script>
  <script src="js/controllers.js"></script>
  <script src="js/filters.js"></script>
  <script src="js/directives.js"></script>

    <script>
        var app = angular.module('myApp',[]);

        app.directive('myDirective',function(){

            return function(scope, element,attrs) {
                element.bind('click',function() {alert('click')});
            };

        });
    </script>
</head>
<body ng-app="myApp">
    <div >
        <button my-directive>Click Me!</button>
    </div>
    <h1>{{2+3}}</h1>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

i forgot to add below line to my HTML code after i add problem has resolved.

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.6/angular.js"></script>
```