# my Controller is working fine but Directive is not

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-controller

ok, so this is my AngularJs Controller which have Directive as well.
now when i run application the main page i design for this controller is working but when i tried to re-use it as directive then i cant see anything, the new HTML page is empty.

AngularJS Controller:

```
var app = angular.module('dropDown', []);
app.controller('DropDownController', function ($scope, $http) {
GetCountries();  
function GetCountries() {
    $http({
        method: 'Get',
        url: '/Home/GetCountries'
    }).success(function (data) {
        $scope.countries = data;
    }).error(function (data) {
        $scope.message = 'Unexpected Error';
    });
}

$scope.GetStates = function () {
    var countryId = $scope.country;
    if (countryId) {
        $http({
            method: 'POST',
            url: '/Home/GetStates',
            data: JSON.stringify({ countryID: countryId })
        }).success(function (data) {
            $scope.states = data;
        }).error(function (data) {
            $scope.message = 'Unexpected Error';
        });
    }
    else {
        $scope.states = null;
    }
}

$scope.GetRegion = function () {
    var countryId = $scope.country;
    if (countryId) {
        $http({
            method: 'POST',
            url: '/Home/GetRegion',
            data: JSON.stringify({ countryID: countryId })
        }).success(function (data) {
            $scope.regions = data;
        }).error(function (data) {
            $scope.message = 'Unexpected Error';
        });
    }
    else {
        $scope.regions = null;
    }
}

$scope.GetShippingStates = function () {
    var countryId2 = $scope.country2;
    if (countryId2) {
        $http({
            method: 'POST',
            url: '/Home/GetStates',
            data: JSON.stringify({ countryID: countryId2 })
        }).success(function (data2) {
            $scope.states2 = data2;
        }).error(function (data2) {
            $scope.message = 'Unexpected Error';
        });
    }
    else {
        $scope.states2 = null;
    }
}

$scope.GetShippingRegion = function () {
    var countryId2 = $scope.country2;
    if (countryId2) {
        $http({
            method: 'POST',
            url: '/Home/GetRegion',
            data: JSON.stringify({ countryID: countryId2 })
        }).success(function (data2) {
            $scope.regions2 = data2;
        }).error(function (data2) {
            $scope.message = 'Unexpected Error';
        });
    }
    else {
        $scope.regions2 = null;
    }
}
});
app.directive('dropdowndirective', function () {
return function() {
    restrict= 'E',
    transclude= true,
    templateUrl= '@Url.Action("AddressControl","Home")',
    //templateUrl= '/Home/AddressControl',
    controller = 'DropDownController',
    replace=true

    }

});
```

MVC Controller:

```
using CountryAddressApp.Models;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;

namespace CountryAddressApp.Controllers
{
    public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        public ActionResult AddressControl()
        {
            return View();
        }
        public JsonResult GetCountries()
        {


using (CountryAddressEntities context = new CountryAddressEntities())
        {
            var ret = context.Countries.Select(x => new { x.CountryID, x.CountryName }).ToList();
            return Json(ret, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public JsonResult GetStates(int countryId)
    {
        using (CountryAddressEntities context = new CountryAddressEntities())
        {
            var ret = context.States.Where(x => x.CountryID == countryId).Select(x => new { x.StateID, x.StateName }).ToList();
            return Json(ret);
        }
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public JsonResult GetRegion(int countryId)
    {
        using (CountryAddressEntities context = new CountryAddressEntities())
        {
            var ret = context.Regions.Where(x => x.CountryID == countryId).Select(x => new { x.RegionID, x.RegionName }).ToList();
            return Json(ret);
        }
    }

    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }

    public ActionResult Testing()
    {
        return View();
    }
}
}
```

My Main-Page
AddressControl.cshtml

```
@{
    Layout = null;
}

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html data-ng-app="dropDown">
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <title>Multi-National Address</title>
    <script src="~/Scripts/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="~/Scripts/cascade.js"></script>
</head>
<body data-ng-controller="DropDownController">
    <table class="container">
        <tr>
            <td><b>Billing Address</b></td>
            <td><b>Shipping Address</b></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <div>
                    <div>
                        <form name="mainForm" data-ng-submit="sendForm()" novalidate>
                            <div class="error">{{message}}</div>
                            <div>
                                <table>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td>
                                            <label>Select Country: </label>
                                        </td>
                                        <td>
                                            <select data-ng-model="country" data-ng-options="c.CountryID as c.CountryName for c in countries" data-ng-change="GetStates()">
                                                <option value="">-- Select Country --</option>
                                            </select>
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>
                                </table>

                            </div>
                            <div ng-show="country==1">

                                <table>

                                    <tr>
                                        <td>
                                            <label>Select State: </label>
                                        </td>
                                        <td>
                                            <select data-ng-model="state" data-ng-disabled="!states" data-ng-options="s.StateID as s.StateName for s in states" data-ng-change="GetRegion()">
                                                <option value="">-- Select State --</option>
                                            </select>
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td>
                                            <label>Select Region: </label>
                                        </td>
                                        <td>
                                            <select data-ng-model="region" data-ng-disabled="!regions" data-ng-options="r.RegionID as r.RegionName for r in regions">
                                                <option value="">-- Select Region --</option>
                                            </select>
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td>
                                            <label>Address:</label>
                                        </td>
                                        <td>
                                            <input id="Address" name="Address" placeholder="Address" type="text" />
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td>
                                            <label>Address 2:</label>
                                        </td>
                                        <td>
                                            <input id="Address2" name="Address2" placeholder="Address 2" type="text" />
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td>
                                            <label>City:</label>
                                        </td>
                                        <td>
                                            <input id="city" name="city" placeholder="City" type="text" />
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td>
                                            <label>Zip Code:</label>
                                        </td>
                                        <td>
                                            <input id="zipcode" name="zipcode" placeholder="Zip Code" type="text" />
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>

                                </table>
                            </div>
                            <div ng-show="country==2">

                                <table>

                                    <tr>
                                        <td>
                                            <label>Select Province: </label>
                                        </td>
                                        <td>
                                            <select data-ng-model="state" data-ng-disabled="!states" data-ng-options="s.StateID as s.StateName for s in states" data-ng-change="GetRegion()">
                                                <option value="">-- Select Province --</option>
                                            </select>
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td>
                                            <label>Select Region: </label>
                                        </td>
                                        <td>
                                            <select data-ng-model="region" data-ng-disabled="!regions" data-ng-options="r.RegionID as r.RegionName for r in regions">
                                                <option value="">-- Select Region --</option>
                                            </select>
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td>
                                            <label>Address:</label>
                                        </td>
                                        <td>
                                            <input id="Address" name="Address" placeholder="Address" type="text" />
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td>
                                            <label>Address 2:</label>
                                        </td>
                                        <td>
                                            <input id="Address2" name="Address2" placeholder="Address 2" type="text" />
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td>
                                            <label>City:</label>
                                        </td>
                                        <td>
                                            <input id="city" name="city" placeholder="City" type="text" />
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td>
                                            <label>Postal Code:</label>
                                        </td>
                                        <td>
                                            <input id="postalcode" name="postalcode" placeholder="Postal Code" type="text" />
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>
                                </table>
                            </div>
                        </form>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </td>

            <td>
                <div>
                    <div>
                        <form name="mainForm" data-ng-submit="sendForm()" novalidate>
                            <div class="error">{{message}}</div>
                            <div>
                                <table>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td>
                                            <label>Select Country: </label>
                                        </td>
                                        <td>
                                            <select data-ng-model="country2" data-ng-options="c.CountryID as c.CountryName for c in countries" data-ng-change="GetShippingStates()">
                                                <option value="">-- Select Country --</option>
                                            </select>
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>
                                </table>

                            </div>
                            <div ng-show="country2==1">

                                <table>

                                    <tr>
                                        <td>
                                            <label>Select State: </label>
                                        </td>
                                        <td>
                                            <select data-ng-model="state2" data-ng-disabled="!states2" data-ng-options="s.StateID as s.StateName for s in states2" data-ng-change="GetShippingRegion()">
                                                <option value="">-- Select State --</option>
                                            </select>
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td>
                                            <label>Select Region: </label>
                                        </td>
                                        <td>
                                            <select data-ng-model="region2" data-ng-disabled="!regions2" data-ng-options="r.RegionID as r.RegionName for r in regions2">
                                                <option value="">-- Select Region --</option>
                                            </select>
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td>
                                            <label>Address:</label>
                                        </td>
                                        <td>
                                            <input id="Address" name="Address" placeholder="Address" type="text" />
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td>
                                            <label>Address 2:</label>
                                        </td>
                                        <td>
                                            <input id="Address2" name="Address2" placeholder="Address 2" type="text" />
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td>
                                            <label>City:</label>
                                        </td>
                                        <td>
                                            <input id="city" name="city" placeholder="City" type="text" />
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td>
                                            <label>Zip Code:</label>
                                        </td>
                                        <td>
                                            <input id="zipcode" name="zipcode" placeholder="Zip Code" type="text" />
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>

                                </table>
                            </div>
                            <div ng-show="country2==2">

                                <table>

                                    <tr>
                                        <td>
                                            <label>Select Province: </label>
                                        </td>
                                        <td>
                                            <select data-ng-model="state2" data-ng-disabled="!states2" data-ng-options="s.StateID as s.StateName for s in states2" data-ng-change="GetShippingRegion()">
                                                <option value="">-- Select Province --</option>
                                            </select>
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td>
                                            <label>Select Region: </label>
                                        </td>
                                        <td>
                                            <select data-ng-model="region2" data-ng-disabled="!regions2" data-ng-options="r.RegionID as r.RegionName for r in regions2">
                                                <option value="">-- Select Region --</option>
                                            </select>
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td>
                                            <label>Address:</label>
                                        </td>
                                        <td>
                                            <input id="Address" name="Address" placeholder="Address" type="text" />
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td>
                                            <label>Address 2:</label>
                                        </td>
                                        <td>
                                            <input id="Address2" name="Address2" placeholder="Address 2" type="text" />
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td>
                                            <label>City:</label>
                                        </td>
                                        <td>
                                            <input id="city" name="city" placeholder="City" type="text" />
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td>
                                            <label>Postal Code:</label>
                                        </td>
                                        <td>
                                            <input id="postalcode" name="postalcode" placeholder="Postal Code" type="text" />
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>
                                </table>
                            </div>
                        </form>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </td>

        </tr>
    </table>
</body>
</html>
```

New html to re-use directive:

```
@{
    Layout = null;
}

<h2>Index</h2>
<script src="~/Scripts/angular.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/cascade.js"></script>

<body ng-app="dropDown" ng-controller="DropDownController">


    <dropdowndirective>


    </dropdowndirective>

    @*<div class="DropDownDirective"></div>

        <div ng-DropDownDirective></div>*@
</body>
```

Comment: What error message are you receiving?

Comment: no error, but my view is receiving nothing no data travelling from angularjs controller to view

Comment: if i comment out directive section then my application is working data is traveling, but boss want me to write it once and re-use it as many time we want like directive but what i created was controller

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you have a syntax error in your directive where dropDownController should be a string like this:

```
app.directive('DropDownDirective', function () {
return {
    restrict: 'E',
    templateUrl: 'AddressControl',
    controller: 'DropDownController',
    replace:true,

    }

});
```

Not sure why you wouldn't get an error message for that though...

Comment: i have changed my directive as below

app.directive('DropDownDirective', function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'EAC',
        transclude: true,
        //template: '@Url.Action("AddressControl","Home")',
        template: '/Home/AddressControl',
        controller: 'DropDownController',
        replace:true,

        }
                
    });

does this looks fine ?

also i found error when i checked with browser:

Uncaught ReferenceError: angular is not defined

Comment: Now the controller is correct but you changed templateURL to just template, and I don't think that will work - you probably need to change it back to templateURL. Is it currently working for you?

Comment: i tried both but its not working, even that html is not showing into my index page

Comment: Just noticed in your previous comment that you're getting an error "angular not defined"... the problem is probably not with this directive, but with the order that scripts are loading on the page. See this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21440295/uncaught-referenceerror-angular-is-not-defined-angularjs-not-working

Comment: i corrected that, now no error but still there is nothing happening.

can you suggest any tutorial to follow to create directive and controller fetching data from database

Comment: Your googling for tutorials would be as good as mine but your controller and directive look fine at a high level. I'd recommend looking at your $http request to the database, make sure you're handling the promise correctly and not doing the wrong stuff before the data comes back from the server, and I'd use breakpoints in Dev Tools to debug the page load and see where it goes awry. https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/javascript-debugging, also Batarang can help with debugging angular: https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/angularjs-batarang/ighdmehidhipcmcojjgiloacoafjmpfk?hl=en

Comment: can i have your email address, i can email you mu solution for your guidance ......

Comment: i m really stuck with this, only controller is working as soon as i added directive it stopped working.

even i cant see the main page (where i have designed the dropdown, textbox) html or text in my new html (where i m using directive to travel the html from main page)

Comment: Can you get the HTML in the directive's template to work if you add it directly to the main HTML page and put the directive logic in the template and remove the directive? If that works, then the problem is definitely in the directive, so that would start to narrow down the problem...

Comment: ok so i just made changes with tamplate and made it as

templateUrl: "AddressControl"

it worked, its working fine ...... thanks Jordajm ..... :)

Comment: now how can make a checkbox working says same as billing address

what should i do? how should i write and what example should i follow.

Comment: Sounds like a separate question - could you accept this answer as correct, then post another question about the checkbox with only the relevant code?