# Write function test with cucumber + protractor + angular2

Tags: cucumber, angular, protractor

I have some problems when I write function test with cucumber + protractor in angular2.
This is my code

`cucumberCong.js`

```
exports.config = {
    seleniumAddress: 'http://localhost:4444/wd/hub',

    seleniumServerJar: '../node_modules/protractor/selenium/selenium-server-standalone-2.45.0.jar',

    framework: 'custom',

    frameworkPath: '../node_modules/protractor-cucumber-framework/index.js',

    // Spec patterns are relative to this directory.
    specs: [
        'spec/**/*.feature'
    ],

    capabilities: {
        'browserName': 'chrome',
        'version': 'ANY'
    },

    baseUrl: 'http://' + (process.env.HTTP_HOST || 'localhost') + ':' + (process.env.HTTP_PORT || webServerDefaultPort),

    cucumberOpts: {
        require: 'spec/**/*.js',
        tags: '@dev',
        format: undefined,
        profile: false,
        'no-source': true
    }
};
```

`login.feature`

```
Feature: Login

  @dev
  Scenario: Login funtion
    Given go login page "http://localhost:8080/#/login"
    Then input userName "username", password "password"
    Then click login
    Then see About page "http://localhost:8080/#/home"
```

`loginSpec.ts`

```
var chai = require('chai');
var chaiAsPromised = require('chai-as-promised');
chai.use(chaiAsPromised);

var HttpBackend = require('http-backend-proxy');
var proxy = new HttpBackend(browser);


module.exports = function loginPage() {
    var expect = chai.expect;

    this.setDefaultTimeout(500 * 1000);

    this.Given(/^go login page "([^"]*)"$/, function (url, next) {
        browser.driver.get(url);
        next();
    });

    this.Then(/^input userName "([^"]*)", password "([^"]*)"$/, function (userName, password, next) {
        browser.driver.findElement(by.id('userName')).sendKeys(userName);
        browser.driver.findElement(by.id('pass')).sendKeys(password);
        next();
    });

    this.Then(/^click login$/, function (next) {
        proxy.whenGET('http://localhost:3000/login').respond(function(method, url) {
            return [200, {"data": "test"}];
        });
        browser.driver.findElement(by.id('login')).click();
        next();
    });

    this.Then(/^see About page "([^"]*)"$/, function (url, next) {
        expect(browser.getLocationAbsUrl()).to.equal(url);
        next();
    });
};
```

My problem are:
1. Sometime userName and password can't input into element but the resolve still is pass. I don't know why.
2. I want use `'http-backend-proxy'` to mock up data without send request to server, but it don't work, an error is `angular is not defined`. How to mock up data when a request is sent?

Please help me, thanks.

Comment: did you find any resolution for this? please update your question with answer.

Answer (score 1):

regarding 1)

```
this.Then(/^input userName "([^"]*)", password "([^"]*)"$/, function (userName, password, next) {
    browser.driver.findElement(by.id('userName')).sendKeys(userName);
    browser.driver.findElement(by.id('pass')).sendKeys(password);
    next();
});
```

protractor is asynchron. your usage to the callback

```
next()
```

is directly executed after the part

```
browser.driver.findElement(by.id('userName'))
```

so the async part in the previously statement is sometimes fast enough, sometimes later.

```
sendKeys(userName);
```

this results in the feature step to be green, with no control if the protractor thing was done correctly.

you also do not use the chai expect.

Suggestion 1.1: do not use next callback, chain async promises:

```
this.Then(/^input userName "([^"]*)", password "([^"]*)"$/, 
function (userName, password) {
    return browser.driver.findElement(by.id('userName'))
        .sendKeys(userName)
    .then(function(){
        return browser.driver.findElement(by.id('pass'))
           .sendKeys(password);
    }    
});
```

the outer "this.then" function uses the result of the promise chain as exit point, replacing the next() callback to leave the step.

Suggestion 1.2: use chai's expect (also asyncronous with chaiAsPromised)

```
this.Then(/^go to some url$/, function () {
    var targetUrl = "http://example.com";
    browser.get(targetUrl);
    expect(browser.getCurrentUrl()).to.eventually.equal(targetUrl);
});
```

regarding 2),
your response must contain the ng-app tag in the body, see [Uncaught ReferenceError: angular is not defined - AngularJS not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21440295/uncaught-referenceerror-angular-is-not-defined-angularjs-not-working)