# Unit Testing in Jasmine

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, testing, jasmine

I am testing a custom service made in angular JS where there is an error which is occurring. It is as follows:- 
Error during loading: Uncaught ReferenceError: angular is not defined in http://localhost:63342/EmailTests/Unit%20Tests/jasmine-standalone-3.3.0/src/emailService.js line 3
Here is the code

```
describe('Email Service', function(){
var emailService;
beforeEach(function () {
    module('bahmni.registration');
    inject(function () {
        emailService = $injector.get('emailService');
    });
});
it('should have a valid Email ID',function () {
    var parameters={
                    access_key : {parameter:'sdasdafassfa'},
                    smtp: {parameter:1}
                };

    var result=emailService.validateEmailService('https://apilayer.net/api/check',parameters,'someEmail');
    expect(result.toEqual(true));
   })
});
```

How can I solve this?

Comment: maybe it will help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21440295/uncaught-referenceerror-angular-is-not-defined-angularjs-not-working

Comment: in line 3 it should be angular.module

Comment: Nope.. I tried that but the same error is occurring